# UITableView with UILabel SizeToFit get mess when Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, sizetofit

Hi everyone I have problem with my `tableview`, i make Cell with `uilabel` with `SizeToFit` and then calculate the `UILabel` Height for set the cell Height everything work well except when i scrolling my `tableView` the text get weird like one char per line:

My `TableViewVell` Method is:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}


UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
label.text = [someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// Set the UILabel to fit my text;
messageLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[messageLabel sizeToFit];


return cell;   
}
```

The Cell Height stay in the correct Size the problem only with the `UILabel` ...
this the result when i load the view:

[First screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfp0x5nukpiyepx/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-05%20at%2011.34.59%20PM.png)

And this is after i start scroll the TableView:

[Second screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/drnonjhxf0hoki4/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-05%20at%2011.35.32%20PM.png)

Any Help???

Comment: What is messageLabel and is it different than the label one line above

Comment: Where did you create the cell's view. You might want to set label's lineBreakMode property there only.

Comment: awooo sorry i fixed it, i just changed the names to make it simple to read

Comment: I'm Using Storyboard so i create it there and using [cell ViewWithTag:1]

Comment: @Lukas Spieß what exactly you edited?

Comment: @DekelMaman See the [revisions history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16949576/revisions)

Comment: @LukasSpieß where i can see it ?

Comment: You could click the link in my comment above or in general click on the "edited $date at $time" link under your question.

Comment: You can't if it has been upvoted or has accepted answers or answers that have been upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably subclass your cell and clean the UILabel on

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.label.text = nil
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The method `sizeToFit` respects the width of the frame and adjust the `height`. And table view cell reuse the cells. Combining those two behaviors can cause the issue you described.

One of your label, which is very short in content (e.g. in the 4th cell with the word "jio"), is resized with `sizeToFit` and the resulting width is smaller than the original width you intended.

After that, table view reuse the cell and `sizeToFit` still respects the small width calculated from previous call of `sizeToFit`.

Solutions:

1) set the width of the frame to your original intended label width everytime before you call `sizeToFit`:

```
CGRect frame = messageLabel.frame;
frame.size.width = 100.0; //you need to adjust this value 
messageLabel.frame = frame;
```

2) use your row height calculation and set the frame height instead. No need to use `sizeToFit`.

Comment: Getting this Error:
Initializing 'CGRect *' (aka 'struct CGRect *') with an expression of incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')
On the row CGRect *frame = messageLabel.frame;

Comment: ok so it's working great Thanks you very much, but i was needed to you the SizeToFit after all because if I'm not using it the text fill only one row.
Anyway it's work fine with this code:

messageLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    
    CGRect frame = messageLabel.frame;
    frame.size.width = 236.0; //you need to adjust this value
    messageLabel.frame = frame;
    [messageLabel sizeToFit];

Comment: @DekelMaman Yes. For the first solution. I mentioned you need to adjust the width everytime before calling sizeToFit. No need for sizeToFit for 2nd solution.

Comment: Check on XIB or StoryBoard - Autolayout is cheked?

Answer (score 0):

- This might help
  http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/
- The approach in given reference and solution provided by @Verbumdei is nearby same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using autolayout, this can also be solved by adding a category on `UIView`

```
public func sizeToFit(constrainedSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
  var newSize = sizeThatFits(constrainedSize)
  newSize.width = min(newSize.width, constrainedSize.width)
  newSize.height = min(newSize.height, constrainedSize.height)
  self.size = newSize
  return newSize
}
```

The idea is to use `sizeThatFits` with a constrained size to determine the size to adopt and then use the min expected width/height.

Then you just have to do something like

```
yourLabel.sizeToFit(self.contentView.size) // or
yourLabel.sizeToFit(CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: self.contentView.size.height))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set preferred Width property of label. That worked for me

[preferred Width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR5a7.png)