# Adjusting elements and the height of UITableView on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `UITableView` with multiple `UILabels`. The issue is that the text in these cells change dynamically as I receive data from the server. It works fine when I load the view controller. But as I scroll, the height of the cells are not updated as `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is only called once.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Before Scrolling]

[image: After Scrolling]

As I've shown in the screenshot, the question label reduces in size which leads to a gap (shown by arrow).

Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIndentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    }

    cell.question.autoDetectLinks = YES;

    // Used to populate cell from NSDictionary
    [self setDataToCell:cell AtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Here's my custom cell's `layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect frame = self.question.frame;
    frame.size.width = 277.0f; //you need to adjust this value
    self.question.frame = frame;
    self.question.numberOfLines = 2;

    [self.question sizeToFit];
    // Place time below question
    CGRect timeFrame = self.time.frame;
    timeFrame.origin.y = self.question.frame.origin.y + self.question.frame.size.height + 5;
    self.time.frame = timeFrame;
    [self.time sizeToFit];
}
```

So to tackle this situation I called

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[_tableIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

in `- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`
This solves my problem but reduces the performance and the elements jump around before settling even after setting the animation as `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`. Is there a better way of doing it? Should I call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` somewhere else?

Thanks.

Comment: add your - (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here come the edited answer:
The problem is your `sizeToFit` in your `layoutSubviews`. Just follow this link to resolve your issue:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949576/uitableview-with-uilabel-sizetofit-get-mess-when-scrolling)

If you also want the cell and the label to dynamically resize to their corresponding text but at the same time your timelabel to be directly underneath it you will have to determine the size of your uilabel based on the text, font and font-size.
See here for more information:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Comment: I'm doing that. But that doesn't update the frames of the cells that are not visible.

Comment: Is `numberOfLines` set to 0 for the label ? Where do you create the label, the cellForRowAtIndexPath does not help since you don't use the label in this code.

Comment: I've done that in my layoutSubviews in my customcell class. Updating the question now.

Comment: Sorry. That doesnt help

Comment: whats with the answer in the link i provided if you change sizeToFit does that help ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43310/discussion-between-anil-and-david-ehlen)